# javascript onblur() not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textbox and need to be validated after `onblur()` event. There should be error message, if and only if the textbox is empty else no message is displayed on webpage. But I think `if` part of the javascript is executing each time.

```
<input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="fname" onblur="validatefname()">
```

Javascript function

```
function validatefname(){
    var fn=document.getElementsByName("fname").value;
    if(fn==null || fn==""){
        document.getElementById("bubble").style.visibility="visible";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("bubble").style.visibility="hidden";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please let me know what went wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getElement**s** by name, returns a set of DOM element**s**, so you need

```
var fn=document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
```

Comment: Great solution! Can you please explain what is DOM and use of [0].

Comment: @SantoshTeurwadkar DOM is Document Object Model, which is the convention for interacting with elements on a webpage, which are called DOM elements. The method `getElementsByName` returns a set, which is an array-like structure containing DOM nodes. The *array-like* part is what lets you use `[0]` to access the element. See here for info on DOM sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static/28163742#28163742 and here for info on DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the input element in the validation function as follows:

```
<input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="fname" onblur="validatefname(this)">
```

And access the same inside your validate function as below

```
function validatefname(elem){ 
 var fn=elem.value; 
 if(fn==null||fn=="")
 { 
   document.getElementById("bubble").style.visibility="visible"; 
   return false; 
  } 
  else{ 
   document.getElementById("bubble").style.visibility="hidden";
    return true; 
  }
}
```

Now if you keep your text box empty then it will display the bubble element else not.