# Appending all page <table>'s to respective <div> with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with a lot of posts with `<table>` and a new responsive layout.

When big table elements (lot of content) are opened on mobile devices, even with *max-width: 100%* or other CSS tricks, they get bigger than the screen.

The solution is append tables in a *overflow: scroll* `<div>`, but I can't edit all the post content, so I want to do that with pure Javascript. **jQuery not allowed**.

The objetive is:

1. Get all `<table>` elements of the page that are inside `#post`
2. Get their content
3. Append that content in a `<div class="table_div">` in the same place that the `<table>` is
4. Remove old `table` elements (the ones that are not inside `.table_div`)

I already can get all content from table elements and remove the tables, but the part of the code that *supposedly* should append table content in .table_div do not work.

Part of my code so far:

```
    var post = document.getElementById('post'),
    tables = post.getElementsByTagName('table');

for(var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];

    var table_content = table.innerHTML,
        table_div = document.createElement('div');

    tables.remove();

    table_div.appendChild(table);
    table_div.className = 'table_div';
    document.appendChild(table_div);
}
```

**Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/hmaesta/6mambr93/**

Please, help with just pure Javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeList has two mode; *static* or *live* (ref  [When is NodeList live and when is it static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static)). *Live* means that changes in the DOM are reflected in the NodeList. And NodeList from `getElementsByTagName` is live. In your code, the length of `tables` is decremented everytime you remove `#post table`.

There is some way to solve the problem.

1. Use *static* NodeList. For example, `querySelectorAll` returns static one.
2. Map NodeList to Array. You can do this with `var ts = []; Array.prototype.push.apply(ts, tables);`. And after this, use `ts` instead of `tables`.
3. Keep length and order of NodeList. Use `insertChild` instead of `appendChild` to keep order and to keep `<table>` in `#post`.

Here is example.

```js
var tables = document.querySelectorAll('#post table');
for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];
    var table_div = document.createElement('div');
    table.parentElement.insertBefore(table_div, table);
    table_div.className = 'table_div';
    table_div.appendChild(table);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/boy48ngs/2/

Note: You do not need to remove `<table>` manually in this case. Element cannot has multiple parents and `appendChild` removes the element from current parent.

Answer (score 2):

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58kapuzs/1/):

```
var post = document.getElementById('post'),
    tables = post.getElementsByTagName('table');

for(var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.className = 'table_div';

    post.replaceChild(elem, table);

    elem.appendChild(table);
}
```

I used the [`replaceChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp) method to first replace the `table` element with a newly created `div`. Then I append the original `table` element to that `div`.