# JS: Attempting to remove a css class from an array of objects only removes from half of them

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have several DOM elements in my html with the class "high", I want to get all elements with the "high" class and remove the class from it, I have tried this already (I am using Chrome's console to test the code):

```
var check= document.getElementsByClassName("high");
for(var k = 0; k < check.length; k++){
    check[k].classList.remove("high");
}
```

But the problem is that it seems to only remove the class from half the elements in the array and stop. If I do `console.log(check);` afterwards I can see that the array has had half its elements removed. How ever, this seems to work:

```
var check= document.getElementsByClassName("high");
while(check.length > 0){
    check[0].classList.remove("high");
}
```

I would expect the first code to work, but now that the second one is working, I don't know exactly how and why this happens.

### SOLVED

The Question was answered, but for those interested in seeing this problem in action:

[Here's A Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnrk7jvh/)

Comment: That is pretty baffling.  Doesn't the second one run away (infinite loop)?

Comment: Because [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is live, and therefore "it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live HTML collection which can cause issues when you iterate over the collection and change some of them.

Use `document.querySelectorAll('.high')` instead. It returns a static node list and you won't have that problem.

[More information on HTML collections/node lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static).

Comment: I didn't realize that was the case, you saved me from a lot of confusion and googling!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty logic indeed :

let's imagine the following array

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

you first delete the `0-th` item, this gives you

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

then, second step you delete the `1-st` item (here it is the `2`), this gives you

```
[1, 3]
```

And you stop there, you should not increment the index when deleted, as all remaining elements are shifted to the left. And you have only deleted half of the items.