# why can getElementsByClassName run without "window.onload"

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see below,it will run without '`window.onload`' and var x is '`[<div class="myInput"></div>]`',but not '`[]`'.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("myInput");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myInput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

how and when it put the element into the array?

Comment: Because it is `live HTMLCollection`

Comment: x is `'[<div class="myInput"></div>]'` in chrome ,try by yourself

Comment: @itsgoingdown thx,I understand.

Comment: You can take a look here, good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static

Comment: @itsgoingdown thx,I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements, meaning it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed (in this case, as it loads).

So the value of `x` initially is different than it is when the document is loaded:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("myInput");
        document.write('Initial: ', x, '<br>');
        document.write('Initial Length: ', x.length, '<br>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myInput"></div>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('Final: ', x, '<br>');
        document.write('Final Length: ', x.length, '<br>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

The HTML document is read by the browser from top to bottom.
While in the head, if you attempt to do `x = document.getElementsByClassName("classname")` there are no elements present as the browser has still not read anything after the script tag's 1st line.

Later on the browser would read the `<body>` tag, create elements and if you call it at that point with `onload` you would get the list.

Comment: downvoted for saying correct things with no comment as on why, interesting.

Comment: You can try my code ,and x is `[<div class="myInput"></div>]` in chrome.

Comment: Oh wait I misunderstood the question, so the question is why it CAN and not why it CAN'T? It does seem weird that it can though, but I do not see what the issue there is.

Comment: @Dellirium Downvoted because your answer is wrong and the accepted (correct) one was already posted.

Comment: At the time of me witting this there was no answer. The answer is wrong as I did mis-interpret the question, as noted. The guy asked why it CAN be accessed, whilst I figgured that the question was why it cannot.