# I have problems with the replaceChild, could someone help me?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the `<span>` tags with the tags `<a>`

**My initial html is:**

```
<p>
 <span class="mention" data-label="59c01a091ebfff41906d6faa">Cesar Romero</span> 
 <span class="mention" data-label="59b81da0c9c18e778824447a">Gustavo Medina</span> 
 <span class="mention" data-label="59bcd70b2d488f3c64efbceb">Ramses Coraspe</span> 
 <span class="mention" data-label="59bfd252bfb7a7024070c2f1">carlos valdez</span> 
 </p>
```

**After function executing  the output is:**

```
 <p>
  <a class="mention" href="/professional/59c01a091ebfff41906d6faa">Cesar Romero</a> 
  <span class="mention" data-label="59b81da0c9c18e778824447a">Gustavo Medina</span> 
  <a class="mention" href="/professional/59bcd70b2d488f3c64efbceb">Ramses Coraspe</a> 
  <span class="mention" data-label="59bfd252bfb7a7024070c2f1">carlos valdez</span> 
 </p>
```

For some strange reason the replaceChild does does not the replacement in all iterations.

The code I am using is:

```
function ProcessPost(htmlstring){               

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlstring, "text/html");
    var elements = doc.getElementsByTagName ("p");

    if (elements.length>0){
        for(var i =0; i < elements.length; i++){                    
            var spans= elements[i].getElementsByTagName ("span");
            for(var j =0; j<spans.length; j++){
                var aTag = document.createElement("a");
                aTag.setAttribute("class", spans[j].getAttribute("class"));
                aTag.setAttribute("href", createUrl(spans[j]));
                var aTag_content = document.createTextNode(spans[j].innerText);
                aTag.appendChild(aTag_content);                     
                var parentSpan = spans[j].parentNode;
                parentSpan.replaceChild(aTag, spans[j]);                                                                        
            }
            console.log(elements[i])                      
        }
    }

}
```

**Has anyone had experience in using replaceChild? Could you help me find what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Please show what your actual result is and explain how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Hi, see the example above, i need all the replacements correct with `<a>` tags

Comment: Change your DOM selection to this: `var elements = doc.querySelectorAll("p span");` and then only use a single loop, since you selected the spans directly.

Comment: uhmm I see! let me try to do this in another way!

Comment: Sorry if this seems silly, but why don't you do something like: `theParentElement.innerHTML = theParentElement.innerHTML.replace(/<span etc>/gi, '<a etc>');` both for `<span>` and `</span>`? Since you must not only replace the tags, but also some attibutes. I actually think this could be rendered faster for a large number of items

Comment: the doc.querySelectorAll ("p span") is only using a single item in the object array, I need to iterate over all the possible tags <p>

Comment: Use this: theParentElement.innerHTML = theParentElement.innerHTML.replace (/ <span etc> / gi, '<a etc>');

It can be dangerous, the variable htmlstring is text  that the user write, so the user can write for example the word 'span'

Comment: I see, good point. Concerning your question regarding querySelectorAll, it uses as argument a CSS selector, so if you want all `<p>` you should input only querySelectorAll('p'). The main advantage of using querySelector is that it doesn't return a live list (it returns a static list), while getElements... does, and this is not good for iteration

Comment: let me try with querySelectorAll

Comment: i tried with querySelectorAll and it is working correct now, thanks guys.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **querySelectorAll**

```
function sendPost(){                

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(vm.textEditor.doc, "text/html");
    var elements = doc.querySelectorAll('p');

    if (elements.length>0){
        for(var i =0; i < elements.length; i++){                    
            var spans= elements[i].querySelectorAll("span");
            for(var j =0; j<spans.length; j++){
                var aTag = document.createElement("a");
                aTag.setAttribute("class", spans[j].getAttribute("class"));
                aTag.setAttribute("href", createUrl(spans[j]));
                var aTag_content = document.createTextNode(spans[j].innerText);
                aTag.appendChild(aTag_content);                     
                var parentSpan = spans[j].parentNode;
                parentSpan.replaceChild(aTag, spans[j]);                                                                        
            }
            console.log(elements[i])                      
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest also including the explanation for why this works: querySelector returns a static list, so every time you iterate and change the tag of one item in the list, the list remains the same (static). Meanwhile, using getElementsByTagName returns a live list, so each time an element of that list (sorted by *tag name*) has its tag changed to something else, it is removed from the list. That means that list[1] will now refer to something else (because a previous item was removed from the list, so it is one element shorter), since it's a *live list*