# Why does my function return undefined when calling document.getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to create a simple switch using css/JavaScript. In the following  you can see that im calling

```
document.getElementsByClassName('onOffSwitch').style.animation = 'off';
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mojuluz/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

What other code is needed for js to understand im talking about the div named 'onOffSwitch'? Was wondering why this current codeset doesn't work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a [live node list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static) (collection) of elements and you are trying to style the collection, rather than one element within the collection:

```
// Change the animation style of the first element with the class "onOffSwitch"
document.getElementsByClassName('onOffSwitch')[0].style.animation = 'off';
```

Also, because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list (a list that is updated every time you use the variable assigned to the list), it can really hinder performance. In most cases, a static node list is better and you can get that with:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".onOffSwitch");
```

But, the same rules apply. That's an entire collection. You'll need to access individual elements within the collection to work with their properties.

Now, looking at your code, you don't really want a collection at all. You only have the one `div class="onOffSwitch"`, so  you could just get that one element with:

```
document.querySelector("div.onOffSwitch");
```

And then you could work with it directly.

```js
let state = {
  switchG: 'On',
  bits: [0,1,0,1]
};


// Get reference to the div
var divSwitch = document.querySelector('div.onOffSwitch');

// Set up event handler
divSwitch.addEventListener("click", flipSwitch);

function flipSwitch() {
  if (state.switchG == 'On'){
    state.switchG = 'Off';
    console.log(state.switchG);
  divSwitch.style.animation = 'off 1s 1';
 } else {
  state.switchG = 'On';
    console.log(state.switchG);
  divSwitch.style.animation = 'on 1s 1'; 
 }
}
```

```css
.onOffSwitch{
 background-color: #4dc71f;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 40%;
 height: 20px;
 width: 55px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
}

@keyframes off {
 0%{ background-color: green; }
 100%{ background-color: red; }
}

@keyframes on {
 0%{ background-color: red; }
 100%{ background-color: green; }
}
```

```html
<div class = 'onOffSwitch'>On</div>
```

Comment: @Ghoyos You weren't completely setting up the animation properly. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns collection. Specify `index` like the following.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('onOffSwitch')[0].style.animation = 'off';
```