# Live and static DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Doing some research regarding live or static DOM collection. What I got was that a  NodeList is a **live collection** when changes in the DOM are reflected in the collection. It is a **static** collection when this is not the case.

Was reading the following question:

> [When is NodeList live and when is it static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static#)

The answer stated that `HTMLCollection`s are always live and `NodeList` may be either live or static.

However is this still the case? I can't seem to reproduce a static collection. For example `document.querySelectorAll` is supposed (**source**: answer from the link earlier given) to return a static collection but seems live to me in the following example:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hi');

function change() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hi')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function checkvalue() {
  console.log(elements[0].style.backgroundColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">test</div>
<div class="hi">test</div>

<button onclick="change()">change</button>
<button onclick="checkvalue()">checkvalue</button>
```

In this example the elements `NodeList` still updates the color red and thus the elements `NodeList` seems to be live.

### Question:

Are there still live and static DOM collections, or do only live ones exist nowadays? If static ones still exist please give an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what's live/static: It's the **collection** that's live or static, not the elements *in* the collection.

If you do:

```
const spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
```

and **later**, you add a new `span` to the DOM, the value of `spans.length` will increase because that new span is added to the collection; `HTMLCollection` instances are *live*.

But if you do:

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
```

and **later**, you add a new `span` to the DOM, the value of `spans.length` will **not** increase, because the new span isn't added to the list; the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` is *static*.

The **elements** are live either way.

Example:

```js
const coll = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
const list = document.querySelectorAll("span");
console.log("(before) coll.length = " + coll.length);
console.log("(before) list.length = " + list.length);

console.log("Adding another span");
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement("span")
);
console.log("(after)  coll.length = " + coll.length);
console.log("(after)  list.length = " + list.length);
```

```html
<span></span>
```

The DOM doesn't really have static elements. If you need something similar, you could *copy* the elements so they weren't in the DOM anymore, so changes you make (to the copy) don't affect the one in the DOM:

```
const elements = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.hi'),
    element => element.cloneNode(true)
);
```

Example:

```js
const elements = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.hi'),
  element => element.cloneNode(true)
);

function change() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hi')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function checkvalue() {
  console.log(elements[0].style.backgroundColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">test</div>
<div class="hi">test</div>

<button onclick="change()">change</button>
<button onclick="checkvalue()">checkvalue</button>
```