# I want to get the font-size using window.getComputedStyle() in javascript but it can't

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
var a = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null).fontSize();
var fontSize = parseFloat(a);

alert("HELLO");
```

That is the code. So I want to get the font-size of a class named menu. Then, I want to alert("HELLO"). But, the alert won't run and when I change the alert into alert(fontSize), it is not working either. Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Have a look at:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_getcomputedstyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass an element to `.getComputedStyle` method. `.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. You either need to select the first element from the set or use `.querySelector` for selecting the target element. Also note that returned object by `.getComputedStyle` doesn't have `fontSize` method, it's a property. You can also use the `.getPropertyValue` for getting a specific value:

```
// select the first .menu element
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
var a = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
var styles = menu.computedStyleMap();
```

styles will give the object which has all the styles available in it. Just print it and check if you got it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

First, [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
expects its first argument to be a single DOM element.
[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
returns a
[`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection),
an array-like object containing a [live
collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163033/778975) of DOM elements. That
is why, if you look in your error console, you should see an error message along
the lines of "TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not
implement interface Element.".

Second, `getComputedStyle` returns a
[`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)
object, which does not have a `.fontSize` method. It does however have a
[`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)
method that you can use to get the font size.

```js
// use querySelector, which returns a single DOM element that is the first in
// the DOM to match the provided query string
let menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

// You can just omit the second parameter if you are not targeting a pseudo
// element.
let styles = window.getComputedStyle(menu);
// get the font size in px
let fontSize = styles.getPropertyValue('font-size');
fontSize = parseFloat(fontSize);

alert('font-size =' + fontSize);
```

```css
.menu {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
```