# document.querySelectorAll returns values only after inspecting DOMs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get these 2 elements having the same class with "document.querySelectorAll(".sc-gHboQg"), but it returns and empty NodeList:

[image]

As soon as I inspect the element:
[image]

only now I can get them:
[image]

As far as I understand these elements are outputted dynamically in javascript, probably react, but how can I get them without having to inspect them first?

Comment: At what time are you getting the elements? are you waiting for DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Could there be another event at play, like mouseover, click, etc. triggering a class change?

Comment: It's not time related, nor at play, mouseover or click on it, I tried them all without inspecting the element in the console, but nothing..

Comment: I believe it's time-related. Try to get them after some time using `setTimeout`

Comment: No, I tried setTimeout, even up to 10 sec it doesn't come up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the javascript console changed scope after you inspect element. Notice how `top` in the first image changed to something else(`mews...`) in the second image.

Your target element is probably in an iframe, or something that is not in a same javascript console scope than the top window?

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that. It's not an iframe though, I just checked the page source and no iframes at all. Besides, do you know how can I overcome this?

Comment: Try clicking on the `top`, and see what causes the scope change in the list? For me it is usually either `iframe` or `extension`

Comment: You were right, in fact there is an iframe, I just didn't see it. Thanks much for your help.