# Element is not ":visible" if loaded in iFrame

Tags: html, jquery, mutation-observers

My site's scenario is as following:

1. When my page loads, it also loads an external Javascript file
2. Page's content dynamically change and we don't care, until a certain element appears, for this I do following steps:
3. A `MutationObserver` is created for `document`
4. Whenever there are changes, it checks with jQuery if `$("#custom-element").is(":visible")`
5. If that's the case run some customization function and detach the observer

My problem:

- If the page is loaded normally, everything works just fine.
- However my page is designed to be used as an iFrame embed, and when loaded through iFrame the second part of step 4 does not work and `$("#custom-element")` returns empty (testing with `querySelector` returns `null`), even if the element is already there. Inspecting the element in the toolbox seems to "activate" the element, and only after that the custom function is run.

I already had a look at:

- [document.querySelector works in console but not on realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176564/document-queryselector-works-in-console-but-not-on-realtime)
- [document.querySelectorAll returns values only after inspecting DOMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418650/document-queryselectorall-returns-values-only-after-inspecting-doms)

But the script is loaded in iFrame's `<head>` tag and both the testing page and the embed page are on the same domain (for testing purposes), so these question do not solve my problem.

My guess is: it has something to do with how MutationObserver is created, but I am not sure.

Here is the observer code part:

```js
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, obs) => {
        const element = $("#custom-element");
        console.log("debug: mutation observer triggered");

        if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
            console.log("debug: visible");
            elementVisibleAction();
            obs.disconnect();
            return;
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
```

To further clarify it for some readers (as a response to the comments):

- The JS code is inside iFrame and it tries to get an element from inside that same iframe
- The JS code runs fine, if the url of the iFrame is loaded like a normal page
- The iFrame is in viewport and it renders right before my eyes. The `debug: mutation observer triggered` is being print to console
- Not only `:visible` returns false, but the `$("#custom-element")` is empty, this is the main problem

Comment: _"My guess is: it has something to do with how MutationObserver is created, but I am not sure."_ - could be, or could not be. How could we possibly tell, when you don't show relevant code? None of us here currently know, how exactly you set this up.

Comment: *Element is not ":visible" if loaded in iFrame* - probably because it's not part of the page's DOM - it's part of the iframe's DOM.

Comment: @freedomn-m, the script is loaded inside iFrame

Comment: Modern browsers arguably don't render anything in iframes that aren't inside the visible viewport.

Comment: If your code is running in an iframe and the element you want to select is outside of it then you are in the wrong scope. You need to use $(window.top.document).find("selector") to change your scope to the correct document

Comment: @LuisLobo, no my code is inside iframe and fetched an element from inside the iframe

Comment: @wOxxOm, no my iframe is visible and all the other code is run just fine

Comment: @Dmitry Your code may be inside the iframe, but if the element you are looking for is outside then you need to do it the way I said.

Comment: @LuisLobo as already said, the element is inside the iframe as well

Comment: @Dmitry You didn't say it, you edited it...

Comment: @LuisLobo no, it was clear already from my initial post. "page's content dynamically change", "If the page is loaded normally, everything works just fine.", etc.   I would like to move this discussion to chat, but unfortunately not enough karma yet.