# Why DOM methods behavior is uncertain in function which renders element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I was just trying to use document methods like `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementById`, and consoling the output. However strange thing is that only `getElementById` is not working, it logs `null`. I have tried className with App and TagName h1, works perfectly. Can anyone shed light on this?
This is code sandbox [ https://codesandbox.io/s/813mnx1vq2 ].

Below is my code of `App` which I am rendering,

```
function App() {

  { console.log(document.getElementById('heading1')) }

  /*
  { console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("h1")) }
  // Output: HtmlCollection array which contains element with id=heading1
  */

  /*
  { console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("App")) }
  // Output: HtmlCollection array which contains div.App element
  */

  return (
    <div  className="App">
      <h1 id="heading1">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

    </div>
  );

}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**PS Edit:** [When is NodeList live and when is it static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static) . Thanks to Jonas.

Comment: At the time that you run the selection, React has not yet rendered the component, and so there is nothing in the DOM matching `heading1`

Comment: then how it works for TagName and ClassName?

Comment: I honestly have no idea - AFAIK, it shouldn't

Comment: Is it because of asynchronous behavior of render function?

Comment: I think you're missing some concepts here. If I understand correctly what you're trying or aiming to do. Then you should add a property to the component and update/access the specific value via the property, vs trying to select an element inside it and then updating it via traversing the DOM & then attempting to update the specific node element.

Comment: Both `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` are synchronous, so regardless of if `render` is async or not, both should not give anything back because they run _and finish_ before the `return` from the `render` ever happens.

Comment: @RohanBüchner  I just wanted to know why it's behaving like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of different data structures returned from these methods, one is a `NodeList`, the other one is one single node. The special thing about NodeLists is that they are live, which means that if a node gets added to the DOM it also gets added to the NodeList. In the console you see a live version of the things logged, therefore you also see elements that are not yet in the DOM with `getElementsByTagName` and you get no result with `getElementByID`.

Nevertheless you shouldn't use them at all when using React.

Comment: Yeah, I know I shouldn't be using. I was just experimenting with different things. Can you provide some reference for it to know more about?

Comment: Amazing didn't know that thing. Thanks again

Comment: NodeLists aren't necessarily live. Typically, older NodeLists like those from *getElementsByTagName* and *childNodes* are live, but newer ones from *document.querySelectorAll* are static.

Comment: I also didn't actively realize what was happening (one of those things I just took for granted/never looked into). But here is an interesting visualisation. If you look at the 2 sets of logs (in this fork of the sample). https://codesandbox.io/s/6vkjw1rl3z
You'll see the 1st set, as @Vivek had them, the array *is* empty until you expand it in the console (upon expansion the console *does* show the element which speaks to this NodeList behaviour), and the second log set prints the output as you expected, as by then, React has updated the DOM.

Comment: @RobG true that. Just for ref, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static

Answer (score 2):

The DOM node is not available by the time `getElementById` is called.

A simple solution is to convert the component to a class component and use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
       console.log(document.getElementById('heading1'))
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <div  className="App">
          <h1 id="heading1">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        </div>
      );
   }
}
```

In case you strictly want functional component, there is a library which allows access to lifecycle methods inside functional component called [react-pure-lifecycle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pure-lifecycle)

Comment: check the comments on question please