# Delete function with checkbox and JS doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, checkbox

currently I am making my own project and I faced a problem. I made a code like below to Select/Unselect/Delete checkbox(include its grandparent Element(.layout)).

However, somehow It only works 50%. When I create a lot of checkboxes and try to select or unselect them, it works perfectly fine. But if I try to delete them after selecting them all, it only deletes half of them, and I click it again, and it deletes half of them remain and do this over and over until only one checkbox is left. This is not the only problem I have. When there is only a single checkbox, I can not select, unselect, or delete it with buttons I made. could you tell me what is wrong with my code and how to solve it, please?

//P.S below code is just part of my code to summarize code so I can show you the exact part of my problem. If you need a whole code send me message I will show you :)

thx.

```js
const selectAll = document.querySelector(".select");
const unselectAll = document.querySelector(".unselect");
const deleteIndex = document.querySelector(".delete");

selectAll.addEventListener("click", selectAllindex);
unselectAll.addEventListener("click", unselectAllindex);
deleteIndex.addEventListener("click", deleteDiaryIndex);

function selectAllindex(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  for (i = 0; i < testform.checkboxchild.length; i++) {
    console.log(testform.checkboxchild.length);
    testform.checkboxchild[i].checked = true;
  }
}
function unselectAllindex(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  for (i = 0; i < testform.checkboxchild.length; i++) {
    testform.checkboxchild[i].checked = false;
  }
}

function deleteDiaryIndex(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  for (i = 0; i < testform.checkboxchild.length; i++) {
    if (testform.checkboxchild[i].checked) {
      removeDiv(testform.checkboxchild[i]);
    }
  }
}

function removeDiv(d) {
  console.log(d.parentElement.parentElement);
  d.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```css
.trash{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="testform" class="test">
      <div class="divs">
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="checkboxs">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxchild" id="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="checkboxs">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxchild" id="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="checkboxs">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxchild" id="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="checkboxs">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxchild" id="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="selector select" value="selectall">Select All</button>
        <button class="selector unselect" value="unselectall">
          Unselect All
        </button>
        <button class="selector delete" value="delete">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="./test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I try to delete them after selecting them all, it only deletes half of them, and I click it again, and it deletes half of them remain and do this over and over until only one checkbox is left.

This happens because you are mutating a [live list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static) of DOM nodes, `testform.checkboxchild`, as you iterate through it.

```js
function deleteDiaryIndex(i) {
  i.preventDefault();

  console.log(testform.checkboxchild instanceof HTMLCollection);  // false
  console.log(testform.checkboxchild instanceof NodeList);        // true
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(testform.checkboxchild));
  // '[object RadioNodeList]' (in both Chrome and Firefox, strangely)

  for (i = 0; i < testform.checkboxchild.length; i++) {
    if (testform.checkboxchild[i].checked) {
      removeDiv(testform.checkboxchild[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This table tries to show what happens in the above function when iterating through the checkboxes when all are checked.

|  | i = 0 | i = 1 | i = 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1st checkBox is** | checkboxchild[0] | **removed** |  |
| **2nd checkBox is** | checkboxchild[1] | checkboxchild[0] | checkboxchild[0] |
| **3rd checkBox is** | checkboxchild[2] | checkboxchild[1] | **removed** |
| **4th checkBox is** | checkboxchild[3] | checkboxchild[2] | checkboxchild[1] |
| **checkboxchild.length** | 4 | 3 | 2 |

Only two of the checkboxes get removed because the `length` and indices of `testform.checkboxchild` are automatically updated after each checkbox is removed from the DOM, so that what was the index of a removed checkbox becomes the index of the next checkbox in the collection.

For example, the second checkbox doesn't get removed because on the second iteration of the loop, when `i = 1`, `checkboxchild[1]`, points to the third checkBox, not the second!

Notice also that the loop ends when `i` becomes `2`, as that is not less than the length, which is `2` after two of the checkboxes have been removed.

One solution to the above is to convert the live collection to a normal Array before iterating through it, for example

```js
const checkboxes = Array.from(testform.checkboxchild);
```

Another solution is not to use `testform.checkboxchild` at all, but instead to use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a static list of the nodes rather than a live one.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      removeDiv(checkboxes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

or

```js
const checkedboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
for (const cb of checkedboxes) {
  removeDiv(cb);
}
```

You may also want to consider using the `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` styles as an easily-reversible alternative to removing the checkboxes from the document altogether.

> When there is only a single checkbox, I can not select, unselect, or delete it with buttons I made

This is another issue with using `testform.checkboxchild` to reference the checkboxes.

If only one checkbox remains, then `testform.checkboxchild` will point to that single checkbox rather than to a list of checkboxes, so it will not have a `length` property and be iterable.

One simple solution is to check for the existence of the `length` property first. For example

```js
function selectAllindex(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (testform.checkboxchild.length !== undefined) {
     for (let i = 0; i < testform.checkboxchild.length; i++) {
       testform.checkboxchild[i].checked = true;
     }  
  } else {
    testform.checkboxchild.checked = true;
  }
}
```

or

```js
function selectAllindex(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  for (const cb of checkboxes) {
    cb.checked = true;
  }
}
```

My recommendation is: don't use `testform.checkboxchild` to reference the checkboxes.

Comment: OMG, I didn't expect this specific and clear answer. I don't know how I appreciate you properly. you saved me thanks a lot!!!